# Unable to import the files of napps_sdk.jar in androidstudio

Tags: android

I have added library napps_sdk.jar into my project but i am not able to import any of its files.
Downloaded the sdk from https://github.com/onelogin/napps.

Copy napps_sdk.jar from napps-master/Android/SDK and add it to the app/libs directory for your app.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue? Can you please post it here if its resolved?